# How to make my flash file on website non-clickable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a few /swf files on my site - i'm posting them that way:

```
           <div class="cvreation" style="padding-top:25px;" >
            <object class="flash_banner" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/prod_bann/flashfile.swf" ></object>
           </div>
```

It works great - but when I click on this flash object - it gets me into currenturl/undefined.
How to make these banners not clickable?

Comment: As a variant you can place an absolutely positioned transparent div over your flash )

Comment: @Kir - could you post your solution?

Comment: You could also create a transparent .png or .gif image using GIMP or PhotoShop, and position this on top of the banner.  But using just an empty div with a higher z-index should also work, as in Mateusz's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
       <div class="cvreation" style="padding-top:25px;" >
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <object class="flash_banner" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
                   data="/prod_bann/flashfile.swf" wmode="opaque" ></object>
       </div>
```

[WMODE DOCUMENTATION](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Browser_support_for_Window_Mode__wmode__values)

Comment: It was letter mistake ("widht") not it's covering full banner - but I can still click on it : (

Comment: this way can don't works in all Browsers IE6/7 for example have a Problem with Flash Embeding here you have to use wmode=transparent

Comment: I added wmode to the above answer. You need to choose a mode that allows HTML elements to show over the embedded flash. check here for more info: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Browser_support_for_Window_Mode__wmode__values

Comment: Hey, wmode tag did the job : ) Thank You!